# Определение попадания точки в многоугольник

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

Незнаю какой алгоритм придумать для такой задачи...была мысль с лучом соединяющий точку и вершину но с вогнутой фигурой нельзя применить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Способ 1:

1. Мысленно направляем бесконечный горизонтальный луч вправо из тестовой точки.
2. Обходим ребра многоугольника в каком-нибудь направлении и подсчитываем пересечения ребер с лучом по правилу:

   - Если ребро строго горизонтально, то это 0 пересечений (полностью игнорируем горизонтальные ребра).
   - Если луч пересекает ребро во внутренней точке ребра, то это 1 пересечение
   - Если луч пересекает ребро в вершине и ребро целиком лежит под лучом, то это 1 пересечение
   - Если луч пересекает ребро в вершине и ребро целиком лежит над лучом, то это 0 пересечений.

Если суммарное количество пересечений после обхода всего многоугольника нечетно, то точка лежит внутри.

Например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7 пересечений - точка внутри.

---

Способ 2:

(Мысленно используем полярную систему координат с центром в тестовой точке.)

1. Обходим стороны многоугольника в каком-нибудь направлении и вычисляем знаковый угол, под которым каждое ребро `AB` многоугольника "видно" из тестовой точки. ("Знаковый" угол - если вершина `А` видна "правее" вершины `B`, то значение угла положительно, а в противном случае - отрицательно.)
2. Суммируем все знаковые углы в процессе обхода.

Финальная сумма углов будет [примерно] равна либо 0, либо 2π. В случае 2π точка лежит внутри, иначе - снаружи.

Этот способ является неэффективным в общем случае, ибо требует вычисления значения угла. Однако он становится существенно более привлекательным, если на направления ребер многоугольника накладываются дополнительные ограничения. Для изотетического многоугольника (все ребра - вертикальны или горизонтальны) вместо угла вычисляется разность номеров секторов координатной плоскости (четыре сектора), в которые попали вершины ребра. Для многоугольника, направления ребер которого кратны 45°, вычисляется разность номеров октетов координатной плоскости (восемь секторов). И т.п.

Comment: Хм.. Похоже, должно сработать :)

Comment: [Классическая имплементация](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)